# Определение принадлежности объекта классу с помощью instanceof

Tags: java

У меня есть `Map<Class,Object>`.
В метод передаю объект. Метод должен сравнить объект с классами из `Map` и выдать соответствующий `Object`.
Например, в `Map` есть такие классы: `Number`, `String`, `Collection`.
Если передаю объект класса `Boolean`, то ничего не возвращает.
Если передам `Integer`, то вернет объект, соответствующий классу `Number`.

Пробовал вот так:

```
private static final Map<Class, Object> cache = new LinkedHashMap<>();

public Object getMapper(Object obj) {
    for (Iterator<Class> iterator = cache.keySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Class key = iterator.next();
        if (obj instanceof key) {
           return cache.get(key);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Но в `if` он не видит `key` и предлагает поискать Maven-ом. В чем проблема?

Comment: `instanceof` требует имя типа, а не переменную типа `Class`.

Comment: @VladD а если есть класс, можно получить имя типа?

Comment: @Regent прошу прощение, сейчас исправлю, не убрал лишние куски

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для проверки, принадлежит ли объект классу, в данном случае стоит использовать метод [Class#isInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object)):

```
private static final Map<Class, Object> cache = new LinkedHashMap<>();

public Object getMapper(Object obj)
{
    for (Class clazz : cache.keySet()) 
    {
        if (clazz.isInstance(obj))
        {
           return cache.get(clazz);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```